# How to set tabindex on bootbox?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I have a custom confirm dialog and I want to have the tabindex on the `btn-danger` button so I can submit the form with enter.

How to achieve that?

```
var config = {
    title: 'Confirm approval removal',
    message: "<em>" + self.$label.text() + "</em> is about to be removed. Please confirm the action.",
    buttons: {
        'cancel': {
            label: 'Keep approval',
            className: 'btn-default'
        },
        'confirm': {
            label: 'Remove approval',
            className: 'btn-danger'
        }
    },
    callback: function(result) {
        if (result) {
            self.$approvedCheckbox.prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            self.$approvedCheckbox.prop('checked', true);
            self.$requiredCheckbox.prop('checked', false);
        }

        self.markRequiredFields();
    }
};

bootbox.confirm(config);
```

I tried adding tabindex attributes but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button which has the `btn-primary` class will get autofocus for enter completion. It also works together with `btn-danger`:

```
var config = {
    ...
    buttons: {
        'cancel': {
            label: 'Keep approval',
            className: 'btn-default'
        },
        'confirm': {
            label: 'Remove approval',
            className: 'btn-danger btn-primary' // this button will get the index and will be submitted on enter
        }
    },
    ...
};


bootbox.confirm(config);
```